# packaging structure in MVP for Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns, mvp

I would like to know the best approach for packaging or folder structure for Android.I have gone through many tutorials for MVP pattern , some differentiate using common functionality(activities, model,presenter) and some use the application features (login, main, detail).Does the packaging structure differ with different design patterns?

Which is the best pratice.Is there any supporting docs or tutorials to explain packaging structure in android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Package structure of MVP would be (models, view, presenter) or it can be module wise.

---

In my best knowledge, package structure would

```
--app
    -package_name
      -models
      -views
      -presenters
```

**See my code on [github](https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm/tree/master/MyApplication/android-mvp-material-and-realm-master/src/main/java/com/nileshjarad/realmdemo)**

In this package structure,

1. You can easily apply progaurd based on package structure.
2. It easily indicates project using MVP :)